# how to fix my problem about go back from full screen webview video page

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have page that show a `ListView` of videos which are gotten from urls as a `WebView` cells like that:

```
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="15,0,15,15">
                                <controls:FullScreenEnabledWebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="{Binding viewSource}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

where `controls:FullScreenEnabledWebView` is a custom render like that:

```
   public class FullScreenEnabledWebView : WebView
        {
            public event Action action = delegate { };
            public static readonly BindableProperty EnterFullScreenCommandProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(EnterFullScreenCommand),
                    typeof(ICommand),
                    typeof(FullScreenEnabledWebView));

            public static readonly BindableProperty ExitFullScreenCommandProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(ExitFullScreenCommand),
                    typeof(ICommand),
                    typeof(FullScreenEnabledWebView));

            public ICommand EnterFullScreenCommand
            {
                get => (ICommand)GetValue(EnterFullScreenCommandProperty); 
                set => SetValue(EnterFullScreenCommandProperty, value); 
            }


            public ICommand ExitFullScreenCommand
            {
                get => (ICommand)GetValue(ExitFullScreenCommandProperty);
                set => SetValue(ExitFullScreenCommandProperty, value);
            }

            public FullScreenEnabledWebView()
            {
                this.EnterFullScreenCommand = new Command<View>(DefaultEnterAsync);
                this.ExitFullScreenCommand = new Command(DefaultExitAsync);
            }


            private async void DefaultEnterAsync(View view)
            {
                var page = new FullScreenVideoPage()
                {

                    Content = view,
                };
                page.BackButtonPressed += () => { action.Invoke(); };
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
            }

            private async void DefaultExitAsync()
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            }
  }
```

and my android code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HBRS.Controls.FullScreenEnabledWebView),typeof(FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer))]
namespace HBRS.Droid.Renderers.Controls
{
    public class FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        private FullScreenEnabledWebView _webView;
        FullScreenEnabledWebChromeClient client;
        public FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _webView = (FullScreenEnabledWebView)e.NewElement;
            _webView.action += client.OnHideCustomView;
        }
        protected override FormsWebChromeClient GetFormsWebChromeClient()
        {
            client = new FullScreenEnabledWebChromeClient();
            client.EnterFullscreenRequested += OnEnterFullscreenRequested;
            client.ExitFullscreenRequested += OnExitFullscreenRequested;
            return client;
        }
        private void OnEnterFullscreenRequested(
            object sender,
            EnterFullScreenRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_webView.EnterFullScreenCommand != null && _webView.EnterFullScreenCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                _webView.EnterFullScreenCommand.Execute(eventArgs.View.ToView());
            }
        }
        private void OnExitFullscreenRequested(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_webView.ExitFullScreenCommand != null && _webView.ExitFullScreenCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                _webView.ExitFullScreenCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `FullScreenEnabledWebChromeClient` is:

```
public class FullScreenEnabledWebChromeClient : FormsWebChromeClient
    {
        public event EventHandler<EnterFullScreenRequestedEventArgs> EnterFullscreenRequested;
        public event EventHandler ExitFullscreenRequested;
        public override void OnHideCustomView()
        {
            base.OnHideCustomView();
            ExitFullscreenRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public override void OnShowCustomView(View view, ICustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            base.OnShowCustomView(view,callback);
            EnterFullscreenRequested?.Invoke(this, new EnterFullScreenRequestedEventArgs(view));
        }
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {
            return base.OnCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
        }
    }
```

the whole things is working good except the following Scenario:
1.the list view show videos.
2.open full screen of some video.
3.go back by using android devices back button without change the status of video that it had it before open full screen.
4.the `WebView` will be black blank screen and I don't know why!!!.

but when using the webview button to close full screen it is working good, and when I change the status of video (paused to played or vice versa) one time at least and then go back by using android devices back button it is working good also!!!.
are there some help?.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but no, it is not solved

Comment: I updated an answer.When you have time, you can have a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just was need to focus on content.

In FullScreenEnabledWebview class there is these fun:

```
private async void DefaultEnterAsync(View view)
{
    var page = new FullScreenVideoPage()
    {
        Content = view,
    };
    page.BackButtonPressed += () => { action.Invoke(); };
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
}
```

just modify it to be like that:

```
private async void DefaultEnterAsync(View view)
{
    var page = new FullScreenVideoPage()
    {
        Content = view,
    };
    page.BackButtonPressed += () => { action.Invoke(); };
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    page.Content.Focus();
}
```

for more information see https://github.com/mhaggag/XFAndroidFullScreenWebView, and see the issue (it is related for the same repository) : https://github.com/mhaggag/XFAndroidFullScreenWebView/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be when you click back button, the webview video also is a status of fullscreen.So you need to exit full screen when click back button. Android Back button can be override as bellow:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (Fullscreen)
    {
        exitFullscreen();
        //if is fullscreen ,need to exit 
    }else
    {
        if (mWebView != null)
        {
            mWebView.onPause();
            backToFrontPage();
            //if a small screen, best pause webview first,then back to frontpage       
        }
    }

    base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that what I am trying to do, but it does not work. please reread my question, the problem is appearing when I open the video in full screen and go back using android back button without change the status of video once at least(pause to play or vise versa), if it was paused in the list and I open it in full screen then play it then go back, this work good and so on.

Comment: @LofiMAM Hi, the answer is one logic to solve like this problem. When pressing back button , it should better check the status of video(full screen or play status).When everything be ready for exitting then exit this page.You can share a video or sample project, I will check it.

Comment: I do not want check the status, I want safe back

Comment: @LofiMAM Okey, if this status can result unsafe back ,then need to do that. :)

Comment: Yes, have you an idea?.the job of this page it is an list view of webviews that shows an videos from different URLs and I want a dynamic and friendly open and back full screen, play and pause video and so on;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847869/xamarin-forms-web-view-for-some-videos-from-different-urls

Comment: @LofiMAM You can share a sample , I will check it.